# Will $A$ be equivalent over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ to the $4 \times 4$ identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $4 \times 4$ matrix obtained from the $4 \times 4$ identity matrix by interchanging it's $3$rd and $4$th rows i.e. $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Will $A$ be equivalent to the $4 \times 4$ identity matrix over $\Bbb R$? What will happen if we replace $\Bbb R$ by $\Bbb C$?

Please help me in this regard. Thank you very much.

Comment: Equivalent in what sense?

Comment: @Parcly Taxel equivalent in the sense that the corresponding quadratic forms are equivalent or in other words whether $\exists$ a $4 \times 4$ matrix $P$ such that $P^TAP = I,$ where $I$ denotes the $4 \times 4$ identity matrix.

Comment: The question of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ is actually knowing if $\exists P\in \mathcal{GL}_4(\mathbb{R})$ or $P\in \mathcal{GL}_4(\mathbb{C})$ right?

Comment: If there exists an invertible matrix $P \in \mathcal{GL}_{4}(\mathbb{K})$ such that $P^{-1} A P = \mathrm{I}_4$, then : $A = P P^{-1} = \mathrm{I}_4$...

Comment: Yeah you are right @Bill O'Haran.

Comment: Then I believe jibounet has the right answer

Comment: @jibounet I think you mean $P \in O_4 (\Bbb K).$ Am I right?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_4(\mathbb{K}) \subset \mathcal{GL}_4(\mathbb{K})$ so his/her answer is still relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over $\mathbb{R}$: no. Over $\mathbb{C}$: yes.

Over $\mathbb{R}$: suppose $P^TAP=I$, then $\det(A)\det(P)^2=-\det(P)^2=1$ (contradiction).

Over $\mathbb{C}$: let

$$P=\left(\begin{matrix}
1&&&\\
&1&&\\
&&1/\sqrt2&i/\sqrt2\\
&&1/\sqrt2&-i/\sqrt2\end{matrix}\right)$$

In case you are wondering how I thought of it, I'll add some explanation. First taking the determinant to rule something out is like a routine procedure. Second notice that the equivalence between quadratic forms is equivalent to an invertible linear substitution of variables. In you case, the only part that matters is
$$\left(\begin{matrix}&1\\1&\end{matrix}\right)$$
which corresponds to $2xy$. And I want to find a linear substituion
$$x=as+bt\\y=cs+dt$$
such that $2xy=s^2+t^2$. So what's better than
$x=(s+it)/\sqrt2,\ y=(s-it)/\sqrt2$
Write it in matrix form and you get $P$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

$A^2=I$

$m(x)$ divides $(x^2-1)$

then either $m(x)= (x-1)$ or $m(x)= (x+1)$ or $m(x)=x^2-1$

It is not hard to say that minimal polynomial cant be the first two cases.

and if its the third one then you have the answer.

Comment: $A$ is symmetric and hence diagonalizable. So minimal polynomial of $A$ should contain distinct linear factors. Since $1$ and $-1$ are the only eigen values of $A$ so the minimal polynomial of $A$ should be $m_A(x) = (x-1)(x+1)=x^2-1,$ as you have claimed. What does it follow from here? Can you clarify it a bit more @Upstart?

Comment: actually its the other way around. How do you know that eigenvalues are $1$ and $-1$ beforehand? First you have to find out the characteristic or minimal polynomial and then conclude what the eigenvalues will be.

Comment: Consider if $m(x)=x-1$ $\implies A=I^p$ but is your matrix $A$ equal to a power of the identity matrix?  If $m(x)=x+1$ then $A=(-I)^{2k+1}$ But is your matrix an odd power of $-I$? If both of your answers are no then you are left with the third case which has to be true because you are left with no other choice of $m(x)$

Comment: Why? Characteristics polynomial is enough to determine the eigen values.

Comment: When you talk of enough then $m(x)$ is the polynomial of least degree such that you get to know about the eigenvalues